# How to shift data using Series.addPoint without shifting x axis values in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have a working time history plot that removes one data point as another one is added after two minutes of data has accumulated. The trouble is that after say 10 minutes it is fairly difficult to see the duration of the data set being displayed (even using tickInterval).  Is there a way to display fixed x axis labels after two minutes of data has accumulated?  Specifically, I'm looking for truly fixed labels that do not scroll to the left with the data.

I tried using `setCategories`:

```
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(cats, true);
```

Where cats is an array with sacrificial values prepended that will be removed during the shift, but the x axis labels still scroll left and I don't want that.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I guess the way I previously described what I wanted to display on the x axis is not ideal. A better way to display this time (x) axis would be to have -120 on the far left and 0 on the far right.  This would still require a non-scrolling x axis where the left most data point is over -120 and the right most data point is over 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm following you, you want to shift off the start of the series, but leave the xAxis alone?

You can just set an xAxis min:

```
    xAxis:{
        min: 0
    }
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cTGtq/1/).

**EDITS**

In response to your comment.  I think the easiest thing to do would be to *shift* the data yourself and then use `setData` to redraw the series.

```
    newData = [];
    var seriesData = chart.series[0].data;
    // shift the data
    for (var i = 0; i < (seriesData.length - 1); i++){
        newData.push({x: seriesData[i].x, y: seriesData[i+1].y});
    }
    // new point for last
   newData.push({x: seriesData[seriesData.length - 1].x, 
                 y: Math.random() * 100});
   chart.series[0].setData(newData, true);
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cTGtq/2/).

Comment: thanks for you answer. I was really hoping it was that simple.  However, see how the data gets bunched up on the right?  What I am looking for would always line up zero with the left most data point and 120 (two minutes) with the right most point and those x axis labels would not scroll. However, the data would scroll off the left of the plot using Series.addPoint (or some other solution). Thanks.

Comment: @nomadicME, see new answer above.

Comment: Thanks again.  That solution does what I'm looking for.  It is funny, that is what I was thinking I was going to have to do originally, but then I found the shift functionality in addPoint.  I'm fairly new to HC so thanks for verifying the path of least resistance.